# Identify connected ClientId's in ActiveMQ Network Brokers

Tags: activemq-classic

Active MQ Network Brokers(AMQ1 & AMQ2) configured with 2 brokers and attached to ELB.
1. First Request from client id c1 connectes to AMQ1
2. Second Request from Client id c1 connects to AMQ2.

Since already from C1 there is a connection to AMQ1, it should not connect to AMQ2.
So Is there a work around for this, like getting all connected client Id's in both brokers, If c1 is already connected to AMQ1, will disconnect it before it establishes a new connection to AMQ2

Answer (score 0):

AMQ1 and AMQ2 are distinct brokers, but happens to be loosely connected in a network. There is no such restriction that single client id can't be connected to multiple brokers in a network.

You may be able to [write your own authentication plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html#Security-ImplementingyourowncustomSecurityPlugin) that tries to filter such things out during connect, but I don't see the point.

I suggest you put such logic inside your client instead to ensure only one node is connected at a time. Or use [virtual topics](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) instead of regular topics - that would allow multiple instances with the same client-id to be connected and subscribe to the same topic in a load balanced fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Petter.

Comment: Need one clarification, If  single client id connected to multiple brokers in a network, will it be served with the same message twice?